# What is the best database structure to quickly fetch friends of friends in a large dataset?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, backend, amazon-aurora

We have 10 million users who can interact with 1.5 million products.

In dynamodb (NoSQL database), we have user friendship stored like this:

Friends Table

```
user_id    |    friends
1          |    [2, 3, 4]
2          |    [1,5]
3          |    [1, 4]
4          |    [1, 3, 5]
5          |    [2, 4]
```

In Amazon RDS (SQL database), we have the interactions:

Interactions Table

```
row  |   user_id   |   product_id
1    |      1      |      1
2    |      1      |      2
3    |      3      |      3
4    |      4      |      3
```

By now, when users visit a product page, they can see their friends who have interacted with that product. This is easily calculated!

But what if we wanted to show their friends of friends too?

What is the best way to model the database to achieve this goal? We can completely change the database structure, do some data preprocessing, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I frankly don't why you would store any of this relational data in Dynamo.  That user_id to friends table is expressing a relationship and may best be modeled in a relational DB structure.  Determining friends of friends becomes trivial in that sort of data store via use of a self-join on the table.

That table may look like this (assuming "friends" is a bi-directional relationship as it appears from your example data)

```
user_1    user_2
1         2
2         1
1         3
3         1
1         4
4         1
...
```

Note that this is a many-to-many join table where each friend relationship is described by two rows (the relationship in each direction).

This becomes important when querying for friends of friends, as you  want to be able to simplify into a single index-able query. In other words, you don't need to potentially query the table twice to look at the relationship in each direction - user_1 and user_2 have no specific meaning.

The query might look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.user2
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2
  ON t1.user_2 = t2.user_1
WHERE t1.user_1 = ?
```

Where `?` is the user id in question.

When working with the table, you would need to make sure relationship inserts/delete are atomic in the sense of effecting 2 rows at a time.

An insert might be achieved by a query such as:

```
INSERT INTO table (user_1, user_2) VALUES (1,2),(2,1)
```

And a delete might look like

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (user_1 = 1 AND user_2 = 2) OR (user_2 = 1 AND user_1 = 2)
```

Comment: This looks like it works well for the 1st level of friends, but it won't return "friends of friends".  If user_1 = 1, then it would return 2, 3, 4. How would I see friends of user 2 (derived from being a friend of user 1)?

Comment: @mike-brant, thanks for your response. We store in dynamo because the relationships actually come from Facebook. Also, to our current needs (showing only the friends who have interacted to a particular product), this way saves one sql query to fetch the friends, so it seems perfect. As we have a lot of users, we were avoiding to do your suggested join. Do you think this is really the best way?

Comment: "But what if we wanted to show their friends of friends too?" Maybe I am reading too much into it, but it is misleading. What you are after is if user 1 views a product, you just want to see that users 2, 3, and 4 also viewed that product? Not what friends of 2 also viewed?

Comment: @MikePurcell When user 1 views a product, we want to show their friends (2, 3 and 4) and their friends of friends (includes 5, who is friend of 2 and 4) who have interacted with that product.

Comment: @MikePurcell This does show friends of friends.  The original user in question here is referenced in column `t1.user_1` (thus it is used in where clause).  From `t1` (the first use of table in self-join) you then get user's friends from column `t1.user_2`.  You are then joining the users from `t1.user_2` to the `t2` table (the second use of this table in self-join) on the column `user_1`.  Finally, you get the friends of friends from `t2.user_2`.  You could continue to self-join in this manner to go as deep into relationships as you like.

Comment: @user1860251 There are probably a few options here.  Either the self-join as I have shown, or perhaps a subselect to get first order friends, using that result in a `WHERE ... IN()` fashion to query the second order friends.  You might try testing both ways to see which gives you better average performance based on the number of typical friend relationships in the system.  As long as the fields are properly indexed, you should be able to join while still getting reasonable performance.